# Proving a differentiable function exists.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x>0\}$. Let $f:A\longrightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ differentiable satisfying: $$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$

How can I prove the function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable so that $f(x,y)=h(\frac{y}{x})$ exists?

Comment: I like this question. Going to take it for my students.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function $g:(x,z) \mapsto f(x,xz).$ Since $f$ is differentiable, so is $g$.

To make notation clear let $D_1f $ and $D_2f$ denote partial derivatives with respect to the first and second argument for $f$.  The hypothesis is

$$\tag{*}x_1 D_1f(x_1,x_2) + x_2 D_2f(x_1,x_2) = 0.$$

We have using the chain rule

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,z) = D_1f(x,xz) + zD_2f(x,xz).$$

Since $x > 0$ in $A$, we can write this as follows and apply (*) to obtain

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,z) = \frac{1}{x}(xD_1f(x,xz) + zxD_2f(x,xz)) = 0.$$

Thus, $g$ is independent of $x$.  Defining $h(z) = g(x,z) = f(x,xz)$ we have

$$h(y/x) = f(x,x(y/x)) = f(x,y).$$

Comment: I still can't solve it, could you please solve it or tell me which results do I have to understand to solve this kind of problems? I really am lost.

Comment: OK I expanded the answer.